# How to use filtering in ROW_NUMBER() TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a source table as following

| SN | name | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Sam | OnHold |
| 2 | Sam | OnHold |
| 3 | Sam | NotOnHold |
| 4 | Sam | OnHold |
| 5 | Alan | OnHold |
| 6 | Alan | NotOnHold |
| 7 | Alan | OnHold |
| 8 | Elis | NotOnHold |
| 9 | Elis | NotOnHold |
| 10 | Elis | NotOnhold |

I want to use a ROW_NUMBER() function for rows with OnHold status grouped by name. My desired output is following

| SN | name | status | rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Sam | OnHold | 1 |
| 2 | Sam | OnHold | 2 |
| 3 | Sam | NotOnHold | NULL |
| 4 | Sam | OnHold | 3 |
| 5 | Alan | OnHold | 1 |
| 6 | Alan | NotOnHold | NULL |
| 7 | Alan | OnHold | 2 |
| 8 | Elis | NotOnHold | NULL |
| 9 | Elis | NotOnHold | NULL |
| 10 | Elis | NotOnhold | NULL |

I can reach to the desired outcome by doing following

```
declare @t1 TABLE (SN int, name varchar(10), status varchar(10))
INSERT INTO @t1
Select SN, name,status
from
(
VALUES 
(1, 'Sam', 'OnHold'), 
(2, 'Sam', 'OnHold'), 
(3, 'Sam', 'NotOnHold'), 
(4, 'Sam', 'OnHold'), 
(5, 'Alan', 'OnHold'), 
(6, 'Alan', 'NotOnHold'), 
(7, 'Alan', 'OnHold'), 
(8, 'Elis', 'NotOnHold'), 
(9, 'Elis', 'NotOnHold'), 
(10, 'Elis', 'NotOnhold')
) t (SN, name,status)


select * from

(select SN, name, status, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY SN) as rank from @t1 where   status='OnHold'
union all
select SN, name, status, null as rank from @t1 where status<>'OnHold') a
ORDER BY SN
```

But is there a better optimized way to reach to the desired outcome at once without having to use Union all at all.

I tried the following but it does not give me what I want

```
select SN, name, status, CASE when status='OnHold' then ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY SN) else NULL end as RANK from @t1 order by SN
```

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: Upvoted for tables as tables (not images) and runnable DDL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `CASE` expression:

```sql
SELECT SN,
       [name],
       [Status],
       CASE [status] WHEN 'OnHold' THEN RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY [name], [status] ORDER BY SN) END AS Rank
FROM @t1 t1
ORDER BY SN;
```

Comment: Edited:-Thanks for the clue. I can simply change my code to `select SN, name, status, CASE when status='OnHold' then ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name,status ORDER BY SN) end as RANK from @t1 order by SN`. Will accept your answer.

Comment: Martin is correct, `PARTITION BY name ORDER BY SN` *won't* work for your defined expected results, @smpa01 .

Comment: Why `RANK` and not `ROW_NUMBER`?

Comment: Felt wrong having a column aliased as `RANK` when it wasn't a `RANK`, @Charlieface . :)